# openlayers ProxyHost just work on internet explorer

Tags: jquery-mobile, openlayers

i have some problems. I use openlayers for getting data from geoserver with wms. When i run map and select feature its work but when i work on google chrome. it is not work and it gives me this error : Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

thats my code :

OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "http://*****:8080/geoexplorer/proxy/?url=";

Answer (score 0):

It is working now.

```
 namespace KaskiGIS
    {
        public class Proxy : System.Web.IHttpHandler
        {
            public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
            {
                var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(context.Request["url"]);
                request.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;

                if (request.Method == "POST")
                {
                    var content = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd());

                    request.ContentLength = content.Length;
                    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                }

                var response = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
                if (response == null) return;

                context.Response.Write(new System.IO.StreamReader(response).ReadToEnd());
            }

            public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
        }
    }
```